# Vimeo to JWPlayer Application?

Tags: jwplayer, vimeo, vimeo-api, jwplayer6, video-embedding

I'm looking for an application that can grab the necessary information from a Vimeo video just by dumping the ID into it.

#### The information I would need for it is:

- HD and SD versions of the video
- Holding image
- Name of Video

If the webapp or application could spit out a JWPlayer Script with the Vimeo video in it as well would be amazing. If not, I could probably just add it in myself.
I saw a really cool version that could work, but unfortunately it spits out JW 5.0 and the final version is in a Flash (SFW) file. This is the link to it: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwplayervimeo/

Any ideas on what I could look into? It can be a paid service as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Vimeo API. Like this:

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/41226058/credits
```

You can use a tool like Postman to test this call or just head over to the Vimeo API playground.

Visit this link and click "Make Call"

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos/41226058/credits

This will show you the JSON you will receive with your API call after you've created a Vimeo app in the developer section.

Why do you need to use a JW Player wrapper for the Vimeo video?

Comment: Hi Elon, thank you for the reply! I need the JWPlayer for work mostly, I'm building a little application that grabs the details of Vimeo and plants it into a JWPlayer script. I'll check these links out, they are really useful! :)

Comment: OK let me know if you want help contributing and we'll open source it. Appreciate any upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

Note that only Vimeo PRO members can retrieve the video file URLs of their own videos. It is not possible to retrieve the video file URLs of another user's videos.

The files array that contains the video files will only be returned with the /videos/ endpoint if you are a PRO member: https://api.vimeo.com/videos/[video_id]

Comment: Hey there, cheers for the comment. We are using Vimeo PRO! Thank you for the help! :)